# illegal start of expression

Tags: java, android

It says Expression expected but no recommendations as to what symbol is missing. I'm using android studio. I suppose it's a simple fix I'm just not sure what symbol.

Heres my code:

```
public class CloudActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cloud);
        Button genderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        genderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(CloudActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                                            }
                                        },
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent tnt = new Intent(CloudActivity.this, LogActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(tnt, 0);

                    }
                }, // Where the problem is

                ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your anonymous inner classes (`new View.OnClickListener() {`) wrong. You shouldn't be separating them with a comma but closing them off with a `);`.

For example,

```
genderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CloudActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
  });
```

match up your `{}` and `()` for all of them. So you will want to do the same thing for `button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` and any others you might have.

You can read more about them in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! Don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Try This. You weren't closing your inner classes properly. I imagine you accidentally put commas in place of semi-colons?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cloud);
    Button genderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    genderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CloudActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent tnt = new Intent(CloudActivity.this, LogActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(tnt, 0);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: You forgot the closing `}` at the `onClick` methods